# JavaFX method reference event handling

Tags: java, javafx, method-reference

Theoretically this method reference should work but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

It does however work if I replace the method reference with a lambda expression:

btn.setOnAction(e-> btnPush());

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class NewFXMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Button btn = new Button("Test Button");
    btn.setOnAction(this::btnPush());

    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scn = new Scene(root,300,300);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Method Reference Test");
    primaryStage.setScene(scn);
    primaryStage.show();  

    }

  private void btnPush(){
        System.out.println("button pressed");

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, your syntax is wrong. You don't use parentheses on a method reference:

```
btn.setOnAction(this::btnPush);
```

Secondly, the signature of the method doesn't match the signature of the method defined in the interface. `setOnAction` is expecting an `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`. The abstract method defined in [`EventHandler<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html) is

```
public void handle(T event);
```

So the method passed as a lambda expression or method reference should take a single parameter of type `ActionEvent` and have `void` return type.

The `btnPush` method doesn't take any parameters, so it doesn't match.

(Another way to look at this, perhaps, is that `this::btnPush` is equivalent to the lambda expression `() -> this.btnPush()`, and that lambda expression would not be a valid argument to `setOnAction` either.)

So you can either use the lambda expression as you showed, or you can modify the method defintion:

```
private void btnPush(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Button pressed");
}
```

Now your lambda expression version would be

```
btn.setOnAction( e -> btnPush(e) );
```

which is exactly the scenario for which a method reference is designed:

```
btn.setOnAction(this::btnPush);
```

(And you could, of course, replace the parameter type of the method with any superclass of `ActionEvent`, such as `Event` or `Object`, and it would still work by simple upcasting rules. But you must have a parameter there that can be assigned a reference to an `ActionEvent`.)

Comment: Thank you, that's very clear!

The () were off course a mistake, forgot to delete them after testing the Lambda.

Comment: I assume the `()` were a typo, but wanted to be complete. Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct; it will help others find it in searches.